# How to add additional fields to customer address form prestashop 1.7.5

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add a new custom field to the *customer address form*, however I can't find any tutorial or instructions for doing this.

I know that I can't do it from the BO and I don't know where to implement this.

Could you please help me with the following points?

- Which files should I modify?
- How do I override them and implement the new field.

To add a new field in the *registration form* I found a lot of tutorials and plugins - but none for *address form*.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use an override for this anymore.
Make a custom module with the additionalCustomerFormFields and validateCustomerFormFields Hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the hook `'additionalCustomerFormFields'` in `classes/form/CustomerFormatter.php` and make the same mecanic for address.

To do that :

1. Override classes `classes/form/CustomerAddressFormatter`
2. Override getFormat method to directly add your field or create your own hook

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to modify or override any files for this. You can create a separate module and utilize the following hooks:

1. **additionalCustomerAddressFields**
2. **displayAdditionalCustomerAddressFields**
3. **displayAddressSelectorBottom**
4. 'actionObjectAddressAddAfter',
5. 'actionObjectAddressDeleteAfter',
6. 'actionObjectAddressUpdateAfter',
7. 'actionObjectCustomerAddressAddAfter',
8. 'actionObjectCustomerAddressDeleteAfter',
9. 'actionObjectCustomerAddressUpdateAfter',

The first three hooks are used for displaying additional fields, while the rest are used for validating the address fields. You can refer to this link for more information about PrestaShop hooks.
https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/